# Encrypting Wifi Password When Using Wicd

Tags: networking, security, wifi, password, wicd

Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179544), I'm wondering if there is a (relatively) painless way to "hide" the wifi password(s) that is/are present in the `/etc/wicd/wireless-settings.conf` file.

I travel a lot and worry that, if my laptop is stolen, a perp could boot said machine with a Live Linux OS and then easily steal said network password(s).

Yeah, I know that I'd have lots of other things to worry about, but am looking for a solution to this specific problem...and all of my sensitive user data reside in encrypted files anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things come to mind.

1. Wouldn't they need your password to gain access to the contents of your laptop?
2. You might also consider MAC (address) filtering as an alternative to password/wep/... exchanges. IOW whitelist filtering against *select* MAC addresses.

Tho 2 assumes you are in control of the WiFi portal/server. In the end IMHO I think not having access to the contents of your laptop makes the whole issue moot. ;)

HTH